# Measure volume/mass of a bag of water without weighing scale

Tags: volume, variable-mass-systems

I am trying to figure out the mass and/or volume of liquid inside a sealed plastic bag of about 150 litres (1x0.6x0.3m) without being able to use a weighing scale. Preferably, the measurement devices or method is placed on the exterior of the enclosed volume. Throughout the day, the bag fills up with water and when it has reached a certain mass/volume a pump needs to be activated to empty out the bag. Due to where the bag is located, there are a couple of limiting conditions that make it rather difficult to figure out the mass/volume of the bag, which we need to know to automate the pump process.

The bag is located inside a crawl space - on a (somewhat) flat surface. This prevents the use of Archimedes principle of displaced volume, placing the bag on a plate to measure the mass

So far we have tried a floater device, which did not work well enough. We're also going to try the following:

- Pressure sensors located below the bag to try and measure the head of water.
- A magnetometer that can measure the distance from the top to the bottom surface of the bag.
- A pot meter that measure the volume inside the bag in a similar way as it works in a fuel tank of a vehicle.

I know this problem statement looks a bit vague, but we are truly stuck and in great need of some "outside of the box" thinking. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A picture would help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the bag is flexible, how about a lever?  One end with a hinge is attached to a board on top of the bag.  The other end activates a switch for the pump.